# derivation of return type based on max range of input possible in C++

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, integer-overflow, template-argument-deduction

I was recently asked this question in an interview of C++ where I 
was asked to improve the below piece of code which fails when 
adding two `int`'s results in the result being `long` and return 
type needs accordingly to be derived.

Here the below code fails because the `decltype()` based derivation is not intelligent enough to identify based on the actual range of values of input but the type and derives return type as same. Hence we need perhaps some metaprogramming template technique to derive the return type as `long` if `T` is `int`.

How can this be generalized any hints or clues?

I feel that `decltype()` won't be helpful here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> auto adder(const T& i1, const T& i2) -> decltype(i1+i2)
{  
  return(i1+i2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout << adder(INT_MAX-10, INT_MAX-3) << endl; // wrong.
  cout << adder<long>(INT_MAX-10, INT_MAX-3) << endl; // correct!!.
  return(0);   
}
```

Comment: For class, you can use [User-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides);but for function, only explicit instantiation can specify the type you need, otherwise the compiler will deduct the template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hence we need perhaps some metaprogramming template technique to derive the return type as long if T is int.

Not so simple.

If `T` is `int`, you're non sure that `long` is enough.

The standard say only that

1) the number of bits for `int` (`sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`) is **at least** 16

2) the number of bits for `long` (`sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT`) is **at least** 32

3) `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`

So if a compiler manage a `int` with `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, this is perfectly legal and

```
adder<long>(INT_MAX-10, INT_MAX-3);
```

doesn't works because `long` can be not enough to contain (without overflow) the sum between two `int`'s.

I don't see a simple and elegant solution.

The best that come in my mind is based on the fact that C++11 introduced the following types

1) `std::int_least8_t`, smallest integer type with at least 8 bits

2) `std::int_least16_t`, smallest integer type with at least 16 bits

3) `std::int_least32_t`, smallest integer type with at least 32 bits

4) `std::int_least64_t`, smallest integer type with at least 64 bits

C++11 also introduce `std::intmax_t` as the maximum width integer type.

So I propose the following template type selector

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::true_type>
struct typeFor;

/* in case std::intmax_t is bigger than 64 bits */
template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool,
   (N > 64u) && (N <= sizeof(std::intmax_t)*CHAR_BIT)>>
 { using type = std::intmax_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 32u) && (N <= 64u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least64_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 16u) && (N <= 32u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least32_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 8u) && (N <= 16u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least16_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N <= 8u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least8_t; };
```

that, given a number of bits, define the corresponding smallest "at least" integer type.

I propose also the following `using`

```
template <typename T>
using typeNext = typename typeFor<1u+sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>::type;
```

that, given a type `T`, detect the smallest integer type that surely contain a sum between two `T` values (a integer with a number of bits that is at least the number of bits of `T` plus one).

So your `adder()` simply become

```
template<typename T>
typeNext<T> adder (T const & i1, T const & i2)
 { return {typeNext<T>{i1} + i2}; }
```

Observe that th returned value isn't simply

```
   return i1 + i2;
```

otherwise you return the correct type but with the wrong value: `i1 + i2` is  calculated as a `T` value so you can have overflow, then the sum is assigned to a `typeNext<T>` variable.

To avoid this problem, you have to initialize a `typeNext<T>` temporary variable with one of two values (`typeNext<T>{i1}`), then add the other (`typeNext<T>{i1} + i2`) obtaining a `typeNext<T>` value, finally return the computed value. This way the sum in calculated as a `typeNext<T>` sum and you doesn't have overflow.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::true_type>
struct typeFor;

/* in case std::intmax_t is bigger than 64 bits */
template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool,
   (N > 64u) && (N <= sizeof(std::intmax_t)*CHAR_BIT)>>
 { using type = std::intmax_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 32u) && (N <= 64u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least64_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 16u) && (N <= 32u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least32_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 8u) && (N <= 16u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least16_t; };

template <std::size_t N>
struct typeFor<N, std::integral_constant<bool, (N <= 8u)>>
 { using type = std::int_least8_t; };

template <typename T>
using typeNext = typename typeFor<1u+sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>::type;

template<typename T>
typeNext<T> adder (T const & i1, T const & i2)
 { return {typeNext<T>{i1} + i2}; }

int main()
 {
   auto x = adder(INT_MAX-10, INT_MAX-3);

   std::cout << "int:  " << sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT << std::endl;
   std::cout << "long: " << sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT << std::endl;
   std::cout << "x:    " << sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT << std::endl;

   std::cout << std::is_same<long, decltype(x)>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

In my Linux 64bit platform, i get 32bit for `int`, 64bit for `long` and for `x` and also that `long` and `decltype(x)` are the same type.

But this is true for my platform; nothing guaranties that `long` and `decltype(x)` are ever the same.

Observe also that trying to get a type for the sum of two `std::intmax_t`'s

```
 std::intmax_t  y {};

 auto z = adder(y, y);
```

gives an error and doesn't compile because isn't defined a `typeFor` for a `N` bigger that `sizeof(std::intmax_t)*CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Thank you max66, I will take a look and try to understand the approach. As you say it perhaps its black and white and there are more intercacies to it than simply int->long

Comment: @DeeptiKulkarni - Sorry: I've forgotten an important point. Answer modified: see the `adder()` description.

Comment: I checked with interviewer later on a lighter note of chat and he explained that the above is good enough solution. All they needed was to cover int to long, double to long double.  :)